# Run a task at fixed time everyday

Tags: ios, swift, timer, repeat

I would like to run a function (make an api call) at fixed time everyday, say 10 am and 10 pm daily. What would be the cronjob equivalent in swift?

I tried implementing Timer as:

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()

dateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "NPT") 
dateComponents.hour = 10
dateComponents.minute = 00

let userCalendar = Calendar.current
let myTime = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)

let timer = Timer(fireAt: myTime!, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

The selector function:

```
@objc func updateTimer() {
    print("Hello")
}
```

Instead of being run at the specified time, the selector function gets executed everytime I run the app and not at the specified time. How can I solve this?

Edit: I’ll be needing this to be run from the background as well. I’ll be using location service in my app.

Comment: I have edited the question: I’ll need in the background also

Comment: iOS does not have a cron equivalent. You can schedule local notifications but if the app is not in the foreground then it it wont run. The only supported background mode for fetching data periodically is Background Fetch, but iOS determines how often to run it, not you

Comment: @NishuPriya "App is not opened" and "App is in background" are  different things , plz make it distinct .

Comment: @Scriptable I am using standard location services to get location updates in the app (distance filter applied, with pausing location updates disabled) and have enabled background mode. Doesn't the timer continue to run in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to achieve your goals without using push notifications. `Timer`'s are using run loops and hence aren't working in the background. There's no background mode for making API calls at regular intervals either.

The only option is to send out push notifications from your server at the specified times every day and in response to receiving the push notification in your app, make the API call. Of course you'll need internet connection for push notifications to work, but since you want to make API calls, this won't make a difference as you'd need internet connection for the API calls to succeed anyways.

Comment: How about I set alarm to run everyday and call my function when the alarm goes off? Just a thought, not sure if it will work. Any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: You can't use an alarm to trigger a function call. That's what `Timer`'s are for, but as I've stated they don't work in the background or when your app is not running at all. As I've said there's no real alternative to the push notification solution.

Comment: ok, got it. One thing I would like to know is that if I enable location updates and allow backgroundLocationUpdates, then in that case will the timer still not run indefinitely? I am running timer each time I have a location update, the timer lasting for few minutes and its working fine.

Comment: @Sujal no, as soon as your app is terminated, the `Timer` will stop working. Location updates don't prevent your app being terminated, they just relaunch your app when an update arrives if it was terminated. However, this means a `Timer` won't work in such scenario. Are you actually using location updates for tracking the user's location or just as a background mode for doing other stuff? If it is the latter, your app might get rejected by Apple.

Comment: I am using location updates for location tracking not for doing other stuff. Is app termination solely determined by ios or is there some time limit we can be certain the app will not be terminated?

Comment: There's no certain time limit, since your app might be terminated by the user at any time or the system might terminate it any time to free up memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174235/discussion-between-sujal-and-david-pasztor).